# How to make buttons look same as other elements and vice-versa

Tags: html, css

While assembling a site, I discovered that it's quite complicated to get buttons work with other elements, so that all elements look all the same.
That happens for example in a menu, where some buttons are real buttons, while other are just HTML links to other pages. Other example may be a form, where buttons are expected to be as large as other inputs.
Please see [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/GtnS4/5/embedded/result/) to understand what I'm talking about. **In the example, I want button to look like other elements!**
Some code since SO requests it:

### HTML:

```
Both elements shole be of the same size
<div id="menulike">
    <button>DO SOMETHING</button>
    <a href="#something">GO TO SOMETHING</a>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
div#menulike button, div#menulike a {
    /*reset some default styles*/
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;

    /*Inline or inline-block*/
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    /*colors and stuff*/
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: black;

    /*This is important - size is expected to be the same*/
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 220px;


    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Because they're different DOM elements?

Comment: Which elements are suppose to look the same? The `DO SOMETHING` and the `GO DO SOMETHING` look the same to me (aside from the cursor).

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How to make buttons look the same like other elements, Every DOM element has some default CSS, however, this should be possible to be changed - or am I wrong?

Comment: I made the title more obvious. If you are about to comment before reading the fiddle, please don't.

Comment: @Jordan Google chrome displays the second example as I expect it and the `A` and `BUTTON` look really the same. However, first example is broken in all browsers.

Comment: @TomášZato I would agree with roliveria's answer, you will probably need browser specific css.

Comment: To go maybe beyond only buttons, you may want to consider finding a reliable css reset.  Then you can define everything just as you want it and not worry (as much) about how different browsers will render different elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does this happen?**

The reason your elements do not look the same when applying the same styling is due to default styling applied on elements. This is due to the elements being different. The differences may also be different depending on the browser.

**How do you fix this?**

You simply need to override all the properties that are different between elements. A lot of the differences between browsers can be solved with CSS resets.

**Why isn't my example working?**

Regarding your particular issue, the button has different width because you are not overriding all of the button's CSS properties. Try adding the following to your text inputs:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This should give them all the same width. Alternatively, you can give your button `box-sizing: content-box`, which is the default for most elements.

As for the difference between the button and link, all I can see is the cursor icon when you hover over them. This can be changed with the `cursor` property:

```
cursor: default;
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed the second example has different heights for the button and link in Firefox (I was using Chrome before, which didn't show it). I believe this is combination of both `height` and `box-sizing`. Setting both to the same value for the elements should give them the same size.

I'm only guessing, but I think the reason `height` is needed in this case is because the font is treated differently between buttons and links in FF. Since no height was set, the fonts took up different amounts of space in the two elements, even if it was the same font with same font size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the form elements (buttons, select, radio buttons) are provided by the browser. Each browser/OS have an way to show it. So I think you need to write a separated css block for it.

Comment: And this "*separate css block*" should consist of what?

Comment: @Zhihao have wrote a more completed answer.